# Change label color at run time

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface

I'm trying to change the color of a label when the user makes a click on it. I'm able to set the text color waiting for the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message and doing:

```
hdc = (HDC)wParam;
SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(150, 150, 150));
```

So, I'm trying to do the same with the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message:

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    hdc = GetDC(hLabel);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(100, 100, 100));
    ReleaseDC(hLabel, hdc);
    return 0;
}
```

And previously created the label:

```
hLabel = CreateWindowW(
    L"STATIC", L"Some text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
    10, 10, 100, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL
);
```

This simply doesn't change the color and `GetLastError` returns `0`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, calling GetLastError only makes sense if the docs say so. And for these functions that is not so. And even if it was, you'd need to check return values.

Comment: Must downvote. You wrote WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but your snippet shows WM_RBUTTONDOWN. Also, is hLabel hlobal or not? This question is vague.

Comment: @Xearinox I see UP not DOWN........

Comment: Oh, yes, but see LBUTTONUP vs. RBUTTONUP.

Comment: @Xearinox You downvote because I write a `R` instead of a `L`? Wow, thanks. Obviously, `hLabel` is global not "hlobal".

Comment: No because you make mistake here, but for possibility than your code is wrong, etc. you expected LBUTTON messages, but in your code have RBUTTON messages. Obviously globals are prefixed, etc g_ or c_.

Comment: Also from your code snippets nobody see that hLabel is global variable!

Comment: @Xearinox Even if the code was wrong, that's a reason for a downvote? `hLabel` could be a `static` variable, so that's not important.

Comment: This is important, because if hLabel is not global, GetDC incorrect retrieve device context or fail. But your code is unclear, so downvote. Dont cry, see for example questions from AlwaysLearningNewStuff user. This questions are right.

Comment: @Xearinox Ok, I'll also see, for example, [your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773926/zlib-uncompress/10774141#10774141). Just awesome! I don't think my question is unclear, I just received a wrong downvote from a 2k-reputation user: OMG! I'll cry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest different approach. Introduce `static BYTE` variable called `changeColor` and set it to zero. Then set this variable to `1` in response to `WM_RBUTTONUP` and invalidate your label. Something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static BYTE changeColor;

    // the rest of your code, like main switch and other variables...
```

Then initialize it in your `WM_CREATE` handler like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        changeColor = 0;
        // the rest of your code, if you had any
    }
    return 0L;
```

Now you need to rewrite your `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` like this:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB( 150 - 50 * changeColor, 
            150 - 50 * changeColor, 150 - 50 * changeColor ) );
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

The point is that after you set `changeColor` to `1` in your `WM_LBUTTONUP`and invalidate label, the expression in `RGB` macro will be `RGB( 100, 100, 100 )` which is exactly what you want. You didn't specify where do you reset the color but you will do the same as in the `WM_LBUTTONUP` except that `changeColor` will be set to zero.

Now the only thing left is to show you how to handle `WM_LBUTTONUP` ( or `WM_RBUTTONUP`, I don't know as that part of your question is not clear ):

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
         changeColor = 1;
         InvalidateRect( hLabel, NULL, TRUE );
         // the rest of your code goes here, if there is any
    }
    return 0L;
```

Your question is not sufficiently clear for me to help you further, so I hope this helps.

If you need further help leave a comment.

Good luck!

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I think `InvalidateRect` wasn't necessary; however, it works. Also, why is called like that? The "Invalidate" makes me think I'm disabling a control :P.

Comment: changeColor is odd. Just store the color and call SetTextColor every time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I'm doing, I just pick the `WM_CTRLCOLORSTATIC` trick from these answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the text color when painting the control. In other words, in response to `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

To change the color in response to button up, make a note of the new color, and force a paint cycle with a call to `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: Well, I thought `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` was called only once when the control is created (that's why I didn't use it). I was wrong. Thanks. Here's my upvote but I'll accept the other answer because of the examples.

Comment: You do need to understand InvalidateRect and the Windows painting architecture though. Worth reading up on.